Call to undefined function Livewire\tmpfile() error in production server
i'm having this issue when i host my laravel project on a server, i'm using filament for the CMS. On local host it works completely fine, no errors what so ever, but on a server, i get this error when i upload an image Call to undefined function Livewire\tmpfile().
Anyone have any idea on how to fix it, struggling with it for a day!
please help me!
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/livewire/call-to-undefined-function-livewiretmpfile
i read this and tried no idea it didn't work.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
